# Apply either --enable-shared or -fPIC on in Code::Blocks

Tags: gcc, linker, flags, fpic

As the question states, I need to apply either of those compiler/linker settings. I am using Code::Blocks 10.05. I've looked through all the build settings screens. I cannot find where to apply these settings. I am getting the following on output:

```
-------------- Build: Release in 39dll-4-Linux ---------------

Linking dynamic library: ./39DLL.so
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Release/buffer.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `CBuffer::retval' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
obj/Release/buffer.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to:
Project->Build Options->Compiler Settings->Other Options.

On the left you will see a tree with the build targets. It looks like this:
ProjectName
   Debug
   Release

Click on each node of the tree and for each node enter `-fPIC` in the text box, then press OK to save.
That way the flag will be added for all targets.

Comment: Great! Wish I had this answer before I decided to scrap codeblocks though.... Thanks