# Compiling module on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to compile a shared library (windows equivalent of a .dll) and it gives me the following error:

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

I've never seen this error before. Ever. I'm using codeblocks and g++ 4.8.1. What causes this error?

I'm compiling my own code using:

```
g++ -shared  obj/Debug/src/Bitmap.o obj/Debug/src/Exports.o obj/Debug/src/Hooks.o obj/Debug/src/main.o obj/Debug/src/Platform.o obj/Debug/src/SharedMemory.o obj/Debug/src/SmartJNI.o  -o bin/Debug/libGLXColour.so -libGL.so -pthread  
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/src/Bitmap.o
```

Comment: Did you follow the instruction given in the linker error? Did you Google it?

Comment: I googled the error. I only see DETOUR_END error. Seems similar to mine. I'm not actually sure how to recompile it with -fPIC.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames you may want to take look at: ["Apply either --enable-shared or -fPIC on in Code::Blocks"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11380445/2419207)

Comment: Ah thank you! Wasn't sure why that error was happening in the first place. That worked.

Comment: And also: ["What does -fPIC mean when building a shared library?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/966960/2419207)